# Source a function from example() in R

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

When using `pairs()` I like using the suggested functions `panel.cor` and `panel.hist` (which are suggested in the examples) to eliminate the duplicated upper or lower triangular space and provide extra information.

I would like to source those functions using something like

```
source(example(pairs, ask = F, echo = F))
```

and not get any output (including: `Error in readLines(file, warn = FALSE) : 'con' is not a connection`), *and* not have the example plots print. Is this possible?

As I side note, the reason I'd like the plots not to print is that I want to use this in an **R** Markdown file and not have to look at the `example(pairs)` plots in my document.

Comment: Some solutions have been given but is there a reason you're not just copying and pasting the code into your document?  Personally I think that might make what you're doing a little more transparent and isn't that part of the reason to use knitr?

Comment: I agree, that is part of the reason to use knitr, but the document is a homework project and I'll be graded on my plots and my math not on the transparency of the code that's provided.

Comment: the solutions provided by @mnel should work for you; the error you saw was because `source()` requires a connection (e.g. a file) but `example()` does not really return one; if you want an R script of the examples, you can take a look at the source code of the `example` function (the key is `tools::Rd2ex`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run a chunk that is not included, and does not keep the figures. The functions will be available as the code is run, but the output not included in the document.

````
```{r example_pairs, include = F, fig.keep = 'none'}
example(pairs)
```

```{r test}
exists('panel.cor')
```
````

The output looks like

```
exists("panel.cor")
```

```
## [1] TRUE
```

`panel.cor` exists in the global environment -- you can use it.

### EDIT alternative

You could also use the `give.lines` argument and save the source code yourself

```
.ex <- example(pairs, give.lines = T)
# find the code in question (look for assignment / scope delimiters)
which(grepl(.ex, pattern = "(panel.hist <-)|(panel.cor <-)|[{}]"))
##[1] 18 19 26 33 34 42

cat(.ex[c(18:26, 33:42)], sep = "\n")
panel.hist <- function(x, ...)
{
    usr <- par("usr"); on.exit(par(usr))
    par(usr = c(usr[1:2], 0, 1.5) )
    h <- hist(x, plot = FALSE)
    breaks <- h$breaks; nB <- length(breaks)
    y <- h$counts; y <- y/max(y)
    rect(breaks[-nB], 0, breaks[-1], y, col="cyan", ...)
}
panel.cor <- function(x, y, digits=2, prefix="", cex.cor, ...)
{
    usr <- par("usr"); on.exit(par(usr))
    par(usr = c(0, 1, 0, 1))
    r <- abs(cor(x, y))
    txt <- format(c(r, 0.123456789), digits=digits)[1]
    txt <- paste(prefix, txt, sep="")
    if(missing(cex.cor)) cex.cor <- 0.8/strwidth(txt)
    text(0.5, 0.5, txt, cex = cex.cor * r)
}
```